# Remove inline styles on an <img> tag and replace with a class

Tags: html, css, regex

I am dealing with HTML code that is image heavy. Problem is, the images are burdened with excess inline styles that I'd like to remove. Here's an example:

```
<img src="Resources/Images/Desktop Advanced Manual 0 Welcome/3000186.png" style="z-index: 67;visibility: visible;mso-wrap-style: square;mso-width-percent: 0;mso-height-percent: 0;mso-wrap-distance-left: 9pt;mso-wrap-distance-top: 0;mso-wrap-distance-right: 9pt;mso-wrap-distance-bottom: 0;mso-position-horizontal: absolute;mso-position-horizontal-relative: text;mso-position-vertical: absolute;mso-position-vertical-relative: text;mso-width-percent: 0;mso-height-percent: 0;mso-width-relative: page;mso-height-relative: page;margin-left: 0.3pt;width: 346px;height: 113px;" />
```

While a search and replace would be wonderful, the width and height and margin-left, etc changes with each image.

What I've been doing is going to each `<img>` tag, removing the inline styles in each and replacing it with `class="screenshot"`.

When I'm done, the code looks like this:

```
<img src="Resources/Images/Desktop Advanced Manual 0 Welcome/3000186.png" class="screenshot" />
```

Wonderful - but there are hundreds of images in hundreds of files.

Does someone have a way to do this more efficiently? I am not proficient AT ALL with PHP or JavaScript. Maybe some awesome regex that would help?

Comment: Regular expressions are present in pretty much every programming language. Which one are you planning to use? If you decided, show us some attempts.

Comment: Remove the image element and add it back..is one of the solutions...Otherwise you'll have to use jquery on each css property to cancel it out

Comment: Are you sure - like dead sure -  you're going to do this with regex? If so, what's the flavour of your regex engine?

Comment: Oh, NOT AT ALL dead sure I want to do this with regex. I'm open to anything that would help with this - but keep in mind that I'm not a hard-core coder. I'm an online help developer.

Comment: Do you want to do this on-the-fly every time HTML is loaded into the browser (which would be a lot of intense repeated processing), or just do it once ahead of time in the source files so that the styles are permanently separated to begin with each time the HTML is loaded into a browser?

Comment: @ajp15243 I'd prefer to permanently remove the inline styles and replace it with the class. Essentially, fix it once in the source code with nice, pretty code in the compiled output. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: I don't understand... why don't you use notepad++ or sublime text regex to add and remove your needs

Comment: @imbondbaby because I don't know how to do that.

Comment: @imbondbaby I know those tools can do replacement across multiple files, but that's not functionality that someone would necessarily know about, and the given situation of `literally hundreds of images in hundreds of files` might make it seem a daunting task, and text editors might not come to mind immediately. Perhaps you could edit your answer and describe how to do it?

Comment: I updated it, did not test it as I am not near a P.C but I believe it is correct.

Comment: If each image has different stuff in the inline style tag, you'll have to make a different classes for to represent that different styling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match anything except a quote, followed by a closing quote:

```
style="[^"]+"
```

`[^"]+` matches any character that is not a `"`. Adding the `+` after it means "one or more times."

And replace it with:

```
class="screenshot"
```

Did not test it but it should work in Notepad++(Windows only).

More info **[here](http://markantoniou.blogspot.com/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)**

Comment: But he wants to keep the width/height/etc so maybe do `style="([^"]+)margin-left` and then remove the first group?

Comment: @Zwade That is actually close! Only problem is that it will remove the `style="` part too... Can't test it right now, not near a P.C :( Will update when I am near a P.C

Comment: @Zwade Actaully maybe it will work if you replace the whole thing with `style="`